# Is it possible that the user has to press a file instead of clicking to select it in action_get_content?

Tags: android

I have the following code and I realized that when the user is going to select more than one file, he has to leave the first one pressed and then he can select or deselect more, and to confirm that they are the ones he wants click on open.

```
private void showFileChooser(String type) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    intent.setType(type);
    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),
                FILE_SELECT_CODE);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

However, when you only want one, click on the file and automatically send it to the 'onActivityResult'.
Is it possible to change the behavior so that it does not go to the 'onActivityResult' when you click on a file if not until you leave it pressed and click on the open button?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is system provided UI, so no, you can't change its behavior.